# How not to get "get make: *** No rule to make target" for goal parameters

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following target:

```
.PHONY: echo
echo:
    @echo "parameters:" $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

When I execute it, I get not just the target I specified, but also an error when Make tries to run `make hello`:

```
$ make echo hello world
parameters: hello world
make: *** No rule to make target `hello'.  Stop.
```

How do I fix or suppress the error in the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because Make doesn't know what to do about targets like `hello` and `world`. You want it to do nothing, but it doesn't know that.

So add a ["match anything" rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) that does nothing:

```
%:
    @:
```